# how to sync from local database to server database using codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpmyadmin

I created PHP app in working condition, clients want this app without internet working in localhost and with internet automatically connect to the live server, I am searching google didn't get any code for sync database from local to the server, below shown that code, for localhost

controller:syn.php

```
<?php class Sync extends CI_Controller {
private $tables;
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
    $this->tables = array(
        "test_users" => array("id","name")

    );


    $this->id_store = $this->config->item('id_store');


}

function index() {
    echo '<br>'.date("H:i:s A");
    $newLine = "\r\n";
    $output = $update = "";

    foreach($this->tables as $table_name => $columns ){

        $col_check = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM `{$table_name}` LIKE 'is_sync'";


        $col_exists = $this->db->query($col_check);


        if ( $col_exists->num_rows() > 0 ) { // is_sync column exists for this table 
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM {$table_name} WHERE is_sync = 0 LIMIT 500" ;

            $rows = $this->db->query($sql);


            if ( $rows->num_rows() > 0 ) { // where is_sync = 0
                foreach ( $rows->result_array() as $row ) {

                    $col_val = $update_col_val = $already_exists = array();
                    foreach($row as $name => $val) {
                        if ( is_null( $val ) ) {
                            continue;
                        }
                        $val = $this->db->escape($val);


                        $update_col_val[] = " `{$name}` = '{$val}' ";

                        if ( "is_sync" === $name ) {
                            $val = 1;
                        }

                        if ( "id_store" === $name ) {
                            $val = $this->id_store;
                        }

                        $col_val[] = " `{$name}` = '{$val}'";

                        if ( $name === $columns[0] ){
                            $already_exists[] = " `$columns[0]` = '{$val}'";
                        }

                        if ( $name === $columns[1] ){
                            $already_exists[] = " `$columns[1]` = '{$val}'";
                        }


                    }

                    if ( is_array($col_val) && count($col_val) > 0 ) {

                        //echo $this->table_keys[$table_name];
                        $output .= "SELECT * FROM `{$table_name}` WHERE `id_store` = {$this->id_store} AND " . implode(" AND ", $already_exists) . " ||";
                        $output .= "INSERT INTO `{$table_name}` SET " . implode(",", $col_val) . " ||";
                        $output .= "UPDATE `{$table_name}` SET " . implode(",", $col_val) . " WHERE `id_store` = {$this->id_store} AND " . implode(" AND ", $already_exists);
                        $output .= " ;; ";

                        $update .= "UPDATE {$table_name} SET is_sync = 1 WHERE " . implode(" AND ", $update_col_val) . " ;; ";
                    }
                }
            } // if is_sync = 0

        } // if is_sync column exists 
    }

    if ( !empty($output) && $this->post_data($output) ) {
        $update = explode(" ;; ", $update);
        foreach($update as $upq){
            if (!empty($upq) ) {
                $this->db->query($upq);
            }
        }
    } else {
        echo $result;
    }

    echo date("H:i:s A");

}

function post_data($qry){
    $qry = htmlspecialchars(urlencode($qry));
    $data = "qry=" . $qry;
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL,$this->config->item("sync_server_url") );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, 1);
    curl_setopt ( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array ( 'Content-length: ' . strlen($qry) ) );
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST,1);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_CRLF, 1);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    if ( 1 === intval($result) ) {
        return TRUE;
    } else {
        echo $result;
        return $result;
    }
}}?>
```

after i created code for server:sync_server.php

```
<?php class Sync_server extends CI_Controller {
function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();    
}

function index() {
    if (isset( $_POST['qry'] ) ) {
        $qry = htmlspecialchars_decode( urldecode( $_POST['qry']));


        //$this->connect_local_db();

        $qry = explode(" ;; ", $qry);


        foreach($qry as $q) {

            $q = explode( "||", $q );




            $exists = $this->db->query( $q[0] ) or die ("<hr/>" . mysqli_error() ."<br/>" . $q[0]);


            if ( $exists && mysqli_num_rows( $exists ) ) {
                $this->db->query( $q[2] ) or die ("<hr/>" . mysqli_error()."<br />".$q[2]);
            } else{
               $this->db->query( $q[1] ) or die ("<hr/>" . mysqli_error()."<br />".$q[1]);
            }

            //$this->db->query($q);
        }
        die("1");
    } else {
        echo "qry not found";
    }
} }?>
```

but i am getting an error in database
[image]

please, anyone, help me

Comment: In the first error message, it says that your query is `... WHERE id_store = AND id = "1" ...`. There's not value for `id_store`, which would make the query fail. Since you've tagged the question with "CodeIgniter", why not use their query builder instead of writing the queries manually like that?

Comment: ...I would also strongly recommend not posting complete SQL queries that you blindly just execute without _any_ validation. Build an API where you pass in the values instead.

Comment: *clients want this app without internet working in localhost and with internet automatically connect to the live server*: this doesn't make sense, because you cannot update a server side database without having access (via internet, e.g.) to it

Answer (score 0):

inside your config file define your local database and server database. like this.i hope it will help you.

//database.php

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => '',
//  'hostname' => 'localhost',
//  'username' => 'root',
//  'password' => 'root',
//  'database' => 'alpaca_web',
    'dbdriver' => 'mysqli',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
    case 'development':
        $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
        $db['default']['username'] = 'user_name';
        $db['default']['password'] = 'root';
        $db['default']['database'] = 'database_name';
        break;
    case 'testing':
    case 'production':
        $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
        $db['default']['username'] = 'user_name';
        $db['default']['password'] = 'password';
        $db['default']['database'] = 'database_name';
        break;
    default:
        $db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
        $db['default']['username'] = 'user_name';
        $db['default']['password'] = 'password';
        $db['default']['database'] = 'database_name';
        break;
}
```

//config.php

```
switch (ENVIRONMENT) {
    case 'development':
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/site_name/';
        break;
    case 'testing':
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://server ip or name/';
        break;
    default:
        $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/site_name/';
        break;
```